# How to show different text on same the image by clicking on respective text field. using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have set of text as a button and on click on that button i want to show that text on one image. how to implement this using jquery or javascript.

may be this will help 
http://store.apple.com/us/browse/home/ipod/editorial/engraving_giftwrap

on this page you can see "iPad Engraving Gallery" link i am talking about this kind of stuff.

Comment: Please improve the quality of your question. Some code would help.

Comment: To add to the comment above, you could refer [the about page](http://stackoverflow.com/about) for guidance on how to ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either have an element the size of the image that has the image as `background-image: url(/path/to/image)` and just treat it like a normal element (text and all)

OR you can have the `<img>` be its own element and put a fixed/absolute positioned element over it with a transparent background.

Say that the div that has the text over the image is `#img-text`.

```
$(".text-sample").on('click', function () {
    $("#img-text").text($(this).text());
});
```